# How to maximize excel sheet column limit?

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, npoi

I tried to create an excel sheet using NPOI. I hit on an exception. After inspecting it and searching internet I came to know that the maximum columns an excel sheet can hold is 16384. Is there anyway to increase this limit. Because the data I have to put is more than this limit.

Note: I am using NPOI,c#,Excel 2010.

Comment: Oh no, don't make that many columns. You need to find another solution. Please share why you need more than 16,384 columns as I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: One of the teams in our company gave us a data in binary format and asked us to put it in excel format in format they provided. Now when I wrote the code I hit on this issue.

Comment: Current versions of Excel are limited to 16384 columns.  You can't change that

Comment: Just add another sheet when you reach limit of record in one sheet.